Unrecognized 4xx Errors in API Gateway Logs - Possible Route53 Health Check Issue?
I have an AWS setup involving a Lambda function with an API Gateway in front of it. The API Gateway is secured using IAM-based authentication, and this setup is working correctly—I can make authenticated calls with the required token without issues.
However, I’m seeing some unusual behavior in the CloudWatch logs for the API Gateway. Specifically, I notice unrecognized calls appearing roughly every five minutes. These calls result in 4xx errors, and while I can't see the exact 4xx error code in the logs, I suspect it might be a 403 error due to the IAM authentication.
Here’s a summary of my setup:

Lambda Function: Integrated with API Gateway.
API Gateway: Secured with IAM-based authentication.
Custom Domain Name: Configured using Route53.
EvaluateTargetHealth: Disabled for the Route53 DNS record.

My questions are:
Could these unrecognized calls be related to Route53 health checks, even though I have EvaluateTargetHealth disabled?
If not, what could be causing these regular 4xx errors in my CloudWatch logs?
Any insights into the cause of these unrecognized calls and how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
The set up is working fine when I try to make calls with valid token, I've made sure that there is no call being made other than My manual calls.
